# Maps loading very slowly

Tags: android, maps

My app includes activity of getting coordinates of my current location and then showing the route to a destination for which i have given the coordinates.The problem is it takes hours to load the map and get the route.If anybody could suggest me how to get it done at a faster rate please.And i'm using The Map application present in mobile for getting the map functionality.
Here's the code i'm using

```
package com.map;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapRouteActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
  mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
  mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
 }


 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
 {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {
   loc.getLatitude();
   loc.getLongitude();
   String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +"Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
     Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+loc.getLatitude()+","+loc.getLongitude()+"&daddr=18.5204303,73.8567437"));
   startActivity(intent);
  }
  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
  {
   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
  }
  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
  {
   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
  {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: How are you doing this? I reckon if you use the MapView with a good internet connection it should only take a couple of seconds.

Comment: Hi Reno,i'm using the inbuilt map application for drawing the map.

Comment: Please see the code and tell me why it's taking so long to launch?

Comment: If you aren't using a MapView, why don't you just open the browser to the google maps url with the coordinates encoded?

Comment: as per the requirement of my app,on click of GPS icon,map should load and it should show me the path from my curretnt location to the hardcoded location..

Comment: But the problem is it works for Samsung and not for HTc

Answer (score 0):

GPS takes time to get a fix. It has to scan a lot of frequencies before it actually triangluates your position. The code that you have written launches Google Maps on getting a valid fix. ( on `onLocationChanged()` )

Instead you may use [MapView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). That way your map will be loaded much faster and you don't even have to wait for a proper fix.

Comment: thanks.And the same code works fine on HTC Hero and it doesn't for HTC wildfire.Can you suggest me anything regarding that??

Comment: There is a link to a tutorial in the answer if you did not notice.

Comment: The main problem is it's working on one device and not on others..I mean it takes hours to load on other devices.Could you please suggest on that??

Comment: Different devices have different GPS Chipsets. The one having the problem is not able to latch on to the satellite GPS signal. You can try this test in an open area it might help.

Comment: Thanks Reno, but is there any solution to this problem..It loads up in samsung in a minute but in HTC devices it take hours..sometimes 3 to 4 hours.. So is there any way that i can speed up the loading of my map and GPS connection??